# Resource(s) for becoming financially literate

Tags: investing, europe, books

I'm looking for some resources for becoming financially literate, something for absolute beginners. Can be in any shape or form, doesn't matter for me as long as the content is accessible.
For more context I'm:

- in my 30s
- no debt
- interested in the more long-term solutions
- not much tolerance for risk
- located in Europe

I've searched through this SE and the only concrete resource I have found is the [Get a Financial Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017I25CW8) book. However, it seems to be more focused on US, which in terms of personal finance is vastly different then EU.

Comment: Are you interested in near-term issues involving consumer finance (credit cards, car loans, etc.), purchasing a home, long-term investing for retirement, estate-planning, taxes, or something else?  What country are you in?

Comment: I'm interested in mid to long-term investing, not necessarily for retirement. Basically I have a fair bit of excess income + some money already saved, but I have no idea on what to do with it. I'm located in Finland.